# Import-Csv with multiple files (member is already present)

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0, import-csv

I have the task of batch converting a large volume of txt files that are delimited by a `¬` symbol into a normal CSV with standard delimiters.

I have worked out how to do this in a PowerShell script, but with one problem: If two of the files contain the same header, it fails with the error "the member x is already present".

Is there a way to clear out the members before each import? They write to separate files so it shouldn't be an issue that there are dupes.

```
$filesconverted = 0

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Include *.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $targetfile = $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.Length - 4)
    $targetfile = $targetfile += ".csv"

    Write-Host "Opening" $_.Name "& saving as" $targetfile
    Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Delimiter "¬" | Export-Csv $targetfile -NoTypeInformation

    if ($? -eq $true) {
        $filesconverted++
    }
}
Write-Host $filesconverted "file(s) converted..."
```

Comment: The error means you have two ot more columns with the same name in a single file.

Comment: If that happens (where you have duplicate headers), you'd need to parse the files yourself (which isn't all too hard, assuming that character doesn't show up in the fields).

Comment: The issue seems to be duplicate columns across files, not in the same one, which should be fine for the purposes of what I am trying to do

Comment: You're overcomplicating naming `$targetfile`.  `-Path "$($_.BaseName).csv"` in your `Export-Csv` call.

Comment: *The issue seems to be duplicate columns across files, not in the same one* Your code converts each file individually, so there couldn't possibly be a column name conflict across different files. Please show sample input and the exact error message.